# Postfix stop continuously

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cpanel, centos7, sendgrid, postfix-mta

I just ask this question in unix.stackexchange.com but I did not get any answer. I hope will lucky in here at least. Please ignore the question's stupidity. I am a noob to linux.

I was successfully configured Sendgrid into a Google Cloud Instance which is CPanel installed on CentOS. Here I have done it.

When install Postfix I have to remove currently installed `exim4`. Installation is successful, But I found sometimes Postfix is stopped. If I start using `# postfix start` again it will stopped in few minutes.

Below is the maillog:

```
# tail -n 30 /var/log/maillog

Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/qmgr[15174]: BAD9D110BEAB3: from=<root@myhost.localdomain>, size=3665, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/smtp[15181]: BAD9D110BEAB3: to=<someperson@mycompany.com.au>, relay=smtp.sendgrid.net[167.89.125.25]:2525, delay=152, delays=152/0.02/0.1/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as q4j-M5JVRM61Sw9du237_g)
Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/qmgr[15174]: BAD9D110BEAB3: removed
Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/smtp[15177]: AA9A8110BEAA3: to=<someperson@mycompany.com.au>, relay=smtp.sendgrid.net[167.89.125.25]:2525, delay=577, delays=576/0.02/0.11/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as AcEHW3P5Q5K7PgnA0qvsYQ)
Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/qmgr[15174]: AA9A8110BEAA3: removed
Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/smtp[15180]: B5A5B110BEAB2: to=<someperson@mycompany.com.au>, relay=smtp.sendgrid.net[167.89.125.25]:2525, delay=152, delays=152/0.01/0.09/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as QumlXDnNQHekR3TnPfC_Kg)
Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/qmgr[15174]: B5A5B110BEAB2: removed
Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/smtp[15179]: B29A2110BEAA4: to=<someperson@mycompany.com.au>, relay=smtp.sendgrid.net[167.89.125.25]:2525, delay=577, delays=576/0.02/0.18/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as k-HSDlzjTPiR3mxxXWZj2A)
Jul 28 04:24:33 myhost postfix/qmgr[15174]: B29A2110BEAA4: removed
Jul 28 04:29:35 myhost spamc[15925]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection refused
Jul 28 04:29:36 myhost spamd[1195]: zoom: able to use 996/997 'body_0' compiled rules (99.899%)
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::INET [_]:783 (running version 3.4.1)
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: spamd: server pid: 1195
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 15934
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: prefork: child states: B
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[15934]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:39080 to port 783, fd 5
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 15935
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: prefork: adjust: 0 idle children less than 1 minimum idle children. Increasing spamd children: 15935 started.
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: prefork: child states: BI
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: prefork: child states: II
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: prefork: adjust: 2 idle children more than 1 maximum idle children. Decreasing spamd children: 15935 killed.
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: prefork: child states: IK
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost spamd[1195]: spamd: handled cleanup of child pid [15935] due to SIGCHLD: interrupted, signal 2 (0002)
Jul 28 04:29:37 myhost dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<6cb+IFlVIr1/AAAB>
Jul 28 04:29:38 myhost dovecot: lmtp(15985): Connect from local
Jul 28 04:29:38 myhost dovecot: lmtp(15985): Disconnect from local: Successful quit
Jul 28 04:29:38 myhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<__cpanel__service__auth__imap__x4omw2slm18rtsvbmuqztk47y34ogk65i4b9jtgduyu1py...>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=15998, secured, session=<lGoLIVlV9Ld/AAAB>
Jul 28 04:29:38 myhost dovecot: imap(__cpanel__service__auth__imap__x4omw2slm18rtsvbmuqztk47y34ogk65i4b9jtgduyu1pylltnu7jebtjldvddpu): Logged out in=11, out=470, bytes=11/470
Jul 28 04:29:38 myhost postfix/master[15172]: terminating on signal 15
Jul 28 04:29:40 myhost postfix/sendmail[16036]: fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option
```

I want to know what is happening here and a way to keep Postfix continuously running?

Answer (score -1):

cPanel/WHM is developed to run with exim4 and not postfix. There is no integration of postfix with cPanel. You can remove exim and install postfix but you will have all sorts of problems as in emails sending/receiving, spam filters and so on. I suggest you remove postfix and keep using exim if you want to benefit of cPanel email features. As a basic guideline, you have to use cPanel the way it is unless you really know what you are doing. Email configuration settings within WHM are created for exim. As far as I know postfix integration is on the feature requests list and it was not developed yet and there is no real information if that will be implemented or when:

https://features.cpanel.net/topic/postfix-support

So remove postfix, try running an `upcp --force` to force update cPanel. Normally it should install exim. If not, you can manually install it using yum package manager:

`yum -y install exim-4.89-2.cp1162.x86_64` (that will be the latest stable on cPanel & WHM 64.0 (build 36), running on a CentOS 7.3 linux distro). Alternatively you can just run:

`yum -y install exim`